# Minizinc: optimal ordering on table feature

Tags: minizinc

I have a table with features = {A,B}. B is a column of integers. Scanning the table, when I have a value change in B column, I increment a variable "changes" of 1:

```
if data[i,B]!=data[i-1,B]
then changes=changes+1
```

I want to find an order that minimizes changes and at the same time keep the repetition of a value in B in [0,upper_bound].
I'm thinking to use an array as a decision variable where save the position j for the element i:

```
order[i]=j means i element in data is the j-th element in ordering.
```

How can I model with constraint? This is what I do until now:

```
array[1..n, Features] of int: data;
int: changes=0;
constraint
   forall(i in 1..n) (
      if data[i,B] != data[i-1,B] then
        changes=changes+1
      endif
   )
;
minimize changes;
```

I think I'm wrong using changes as a constant variable, right? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In MiniZinc (and in constraint programming in general) you cannot increment a variable as `changes=changes+1`).

If `changes` is a variable used only for the total count of changes you can use sum instead, something like:

```
% ...
var 0..n: num_changes;
constraint
   changes = sum([data[i,B] != data[i-1,B] | i in 2..n])
;
% ...
```

However, if you want to use the number of accumulated changes for each `i` then you have to create a changes array to collect the values for each step, e.g.

```
var[1..n-1] of var 0..n: changes;
% the total number of changes (to minimize)
var 0..n-1: total_changes = changes[n-1]; 
constraint
forall(i in 1..n-1) (
    if data[i,B] != data[i-1,B] then
       changes[i] = changes[i-1]+1
     else
       changes[i] = changes[i-1]    
    endif
)
;
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It's exaclty what I'm looking for. In this ways I model the ordering with "order" array:
`array[1..n-1] of var 1..n-1: order;
constraint
      forall(i in 1..n-1) (
          if data[order[i],B] != data[order[i-1],B] then
             changes[i] = changes[i-1]+1
           else
             changes[i] = changes[i-1]
          endif
      )
      
      /\
     
      alldifferent(order)    
;`
But in this way it seems the model gets huge time with n large (500). Does exist a way to optimize this ordering? Thanks again!

Comment: @med The performance probably depends on the complete model (including search heuristics together with the solver you use), not just on the `order` array. It would help if you could show the complete model (with some small dataset).